# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor referer none

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm trying to make my spider working.
This is my code in spider:

```
start_urls = ["http://www.khmer24.com/"]   

rules = (
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'ad/\w+/67-\d+\.html',),
    ), 
    callback='parse_items'),
)
```

The sample url look like:
http://www.khmer24.com/ad/honda-click-2012-98/67-258149.html

I want to keep the "ad" and the "67-"

The output of `scrapy crawl khmer24` is:

```
Crawled (200) <GET http://www.khmer24.com/> (referer: None)
```

I can't figure out why
Here is my whole code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "khmer24"
    allowed_domains = ["khmer24.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.khmer24.com/"]   

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'ad/\w+/67-\d+\.html',),
        ), 
        callback='parse_items'),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='innerbox']/h1/text()")
        return(titles)
```

Answer (score 1):

So your question is, "*why is my referer None?*"

The line from your log output

```
Crawled (200) <GET http://www.khmer24.com/> (referer: None)
```

is coming from `start_urls`, not the link extractor.  Requests made from `start_urls` do not contain a referer header by default.  You can manually add headers by issuing the [requests yourself](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).